# Bash expansion error defining function with pandoc

Tags: macos, bash, alias, variable-expansion

I'm using the [advice here](http://blog.metamatt.com/blog/2013/01/09/previewing-markdown-files-from-the-terminal/) to setup an alias to convert markdown to `man` style output using the command,

```
alias mdless="pandoc -s -f markdown -t man \!* | groff -T utf8 -man | less"
```

I keep getting the error: `pandoc: !*: openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`

But the command words fine if I just do `pandoc -s -f markdown -t man README.md | groff -T utf8 -man | less`

Is there something wrong with this bash expansion syntax?

Comment: The code you copied is, according to that page, a tcsh alias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That example is a `tcsh` alias not a `bash` alias. That's why you needed to add the `=` that the original had to yours to get it to work at all.

The problem is that `tcsh` (apparently) removes escaping backslashes from history expansion exclamation points that it sees in double quoted strings:

```
tcsh$ echo "\!*"
!*
```

Whereas `bash` (for some reason I've never understood) does not do that:

```
bash$ echo "\!*"
\!*
```

I'm not sure you can get an exact duplicate of that alias in `bash` since I don't think bash will do history expansion on an alias expansion so the closest you can get is a function that takes files as arguments:

```
mdless() {
    pandoc -s -f markdown -t man "$@" | groff -T utf8 -man | less
}
```